# Add custom user defined Cordova plugin in ionic2 with typescript not working

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I have created custom Cordova plugin. I want to use that plugin into ionic2 that uses typescript and angular 2. I am able to add the plugin into ionic 2 project. But call of methods defined in plugin .Java classes does't work. If class imported in following way:
import Hello from '@ionic-native/hello';

It gives an error "Cannot find module '@ionic-native/hello'".
Please let me know the way to use plugin in ionic 2.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Your own plugin is not part of `ionic-native` so you cannot import it from `ionic-native`. In your `plugin.xml` you should have a `js-module` element which looks something like this:

```
<js-module src="www/yourplugin.js" name="yourplugin">
  <clobbers target="window.plugins.yourplugin"/>
</js-module>
```

If you want to use this plugin you have to tell typescript that `yourplugin` will exist at runtime. You do this with this line of code:

```
declare var yourplugin;
```

You have to add this line in every typescript class where you want to use your plugin at the same level as your imports.

The documentation for `js-module` and `clobbers` is available [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/plugin_ref/spec.html#js-module).

Comment: This must be the accepted answer. In many places, people are talking about window.plugins.yourplugin.method, but, that is unnecessary and results in error.

Comment: where to add this ? Can anyone help me please

Comment: @VikasKrishnan Add this inside plugin.xml file of your custom cordova plugin